# Codeigniter search with pagination is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am trying to implement search with pagination in codeigniter. The problem I am facing is as follows.

> The default url for the searched term looks like this --> `http://guardintel.dev/companies/staff/staff_search?name=riaz&address=&email=`.

But as soon as i select the second page of the link the url changes to the following

`http://guardintel.dev/companies/staff/staff_search/1`

so I am losing the search parameters and the page basically lists all the results from the database.

My base URL is like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . '/companies/staff/staff_search';
```

I have changed the base url to this according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609071/pagination-with-search-in-codeigniter-is-not-working) post (I've hard coded the url to check)

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('/companies/staff/staff_search') . "?company_staff_id=&name=r&address=&email=" ;
```

As a result the url becomes like this

> http://guardintel.dev/companies/staff/staff_search?company_staff_id=&name=r&address=&email=/1

Which  searches for an email `/1`. Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Use `$config[‘page_query_string’] = TRUE;` in your initialize. It will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can use page query string:

```
    $config['base_url'] = base_url('/companies/staff/staff_search') . "?company_staff_id=&name=r&address=&email=" 
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = true;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

So you will have &page=1 in your $_GET parameters for next page.

The URL address should be:

```
http://guardintel.dev/companies/staff/staff_search?company_staff_id=&name=r&address=&email=&page=1
```

This may help you to fix the problem.

Comment: Your solution works as you said, but you need to add another line, `$config[‘page_query_string’] = TRUE;` I am accepting this as an answer.     **Edit** I have found another solution : `$config[‘reuse_query_string’] = TRUE;` in this case i don't have to append the query parameters, it is automatically reused in the url.

Comment: Agree. You got the main idea. Glad to help you.